# How to color multiple text from richtextbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So I made a chat in vb.net (using FTP server) and I want to color each name from my chat
so the file with messages is something like the following:

```
#2George: HI
#2George: Hi geoo
```

and using `RichTextBox1 textchanged` event I add:

```
For Each line In RichTextBox1.Lines
    If Not line Is Nothing Then
        If line.ToString.Trim.Contains("#2") Then
            Dim s$ = line.Trim
            RichTextBox1.Select(s.IndexOf("#") + 1, s.IndexOf(":", s.IndexOf("#")) - s.IndexOf("#") - 1)
            MsgBox(RichTextBox1.SelectedText)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
        End If
    End If
Next
```

the first name (George) changed his color but the second one didn't.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your IndexOf calculations are using the index of the current line, but you are not translating that index to where that line is being used in the RichTextBox.  That is, your second line of `#2George: Hi geoo` is finding an index of 0 for the # sign, but index 0 in the RichTextBox is referring to the line `#2George: HI`, so you keep redrawing the first line every time.

To fix the immediate problem:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
  Dim startIndex As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("#", _
                                    RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i))
  If startIndex > -1 Then
    Dim endIndex As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(":", startIndex)
    If endIndex > -1 Then
      RichTextBox1.Select(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
      RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
    End If
  End If
Next
```

The next problem is that doing this in the TextChanged event re-draws all the lines all the time.  That won't scale too well.  Consider drawing the text before you add it to the control by using a preformatted RTF line.  Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  AddRTFLine("#2George", "Hi")
  AddRTFLine("#2George", "Hi geoo")
End Sub

Private Sub AddRTFLine(userName As String, userMessage As String)
  Using box As New RichTextBox
    box.SelectionColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
    box.AppendText(userName)
    box.SelectionColor = Color.Black
    box.AppendText(": " & userMessage)
    box.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    box.SelectAll()
    RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength, 0)
    RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf = box.SelectedRtf
  End Using
End Sub
```